Expand the data set to include all combinations of the values of the variables using R
I have the following snippet of my data set that consists of thousands of observations

and I want to expand this data set using R so as to include all combiations of the first two columns
that is, I want this output.

I tried using the melt or the pivot_longer but with no success. Is there any alternative R way to do that?
Thank you in advance!
I tried the melt or the pivot function but without success.

expand.grid is what you're looking for, or tidyr::complete

Hi Jon, Is it possible to give an example? Many thanks in advance

An approach using merge on the expanded unique values
merge(df, expand.grid(countries = unique(df$countries), 
                      year = unique(df$year)), all=T)
  countries year values
1        UK 2004    1.2
2        UK 2005     NA
3        UK 2006     NA
4        UK 2007     NA
5       USA 2004     NA
6       USA 2005    4.5
7       USA 2006    5.2
8       USA 2007    3.5

Data
df <- structure(list(countries = c("UK", "USA", "USA", "USA"), year = 
2004:2007, values = c(1.2, 4.5, 5.2, 3.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names =
c(NA, -4L))


df |> tidyr::complete(countries, year = min(year):max(year))

Result

  countries  year values
  <chr>     <int>  <dbl>
1 UK         2004    1.2
2 UK         2005   NA  
3 UK         2006   NA  
4 UK         2007   NA  
5 USA        2004   NA  
6 USA        2005    4.5
7 USA        2006    5.2
8 USA        2007    3.5


One way to solve your problem:
data.table::data.table(df, key=c("countries","year"))[CJ(countries, year, unique=T)]

   countries  year values
      <char> <int>  <num>
1:        UK  2004    1.2
2:        UK  2005     NA
3:        UK  2006     NA
4:        UK  2007     NA
5:       USA  2004     NA
6:       USA  2005    4.5
7:       USA  2006    5.2
8:       USA  2007    3.5

